# What's a quick way to test to see a file exists?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I want to quickly check to see if a file exists in my iPhone app's Documents directory (or any path for that matter).  I can enumerate through the directory's files, or I can try to open a specific file.  What's the fastest way?  I just need to know if the file is there or if it does not exist.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

**Swift v3:**

`let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: somePath)`

Thanks to [Nikolay Suvandzhiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1678420/nikolay-suvandzhiev).

**Objective-C (Original):**

`BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:somePath];`

Comment: Swift 3: `let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: somePath)`