# how to chech image is existing in the folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's a quick way to test to see a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356701/whats-a-quick-way-to-test-to-see-a-file-exists)

I am new to iPhone development. I save an image in the "Documents" folder. Below shows the code which is using for that

```
NSString *fullPath=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",limgName] retain];
NSString *mpngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fullPath];

NSLog(@"saving path %@",mpngPath);
[myImgdata writeToFile:mpngPath atomically:YES];
```

My aim is the next time i want to check this image exists or not in the document folder. How to check this path exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to get `mpngPath` the same way and later use `NSFileManager` to check if the file exists or not.

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:mpngPath];
if ( fileExists ) {
    /* The image exists. Handle appropriately */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you check by doing this:

CFShow([[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents"]]);